# Accumulated methods invocation order in RequestContext#fire()?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, requestfactory

Javadoc for `RequestContext#fire()` says only:

> Send the accumulated changes and method invocations associated with the RequestContext.

[GWT Moving Parts wiki entry](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryMovingParts#RequestContext) under Flow section says only:

> - All accumulated operations will be applied to the domain objects by traversing properties of the proxies.
> - All method invocations in the payload are executed.

But will these methods be executed on the server side in the same order they were "executed" (accumulated) on `ReqestContext` instance on client side?

For my situation, if I execute on client side:

```
context.persist().using(proxy)
context.find(proxy.stableId().to(updatingReceiver))
context.fire()
```

Then may I be sure that on server side `find()` will be invoked after `persist()` so my `updatingReceiver` will get proxy of updated (`persist()`'ed) entity as an argument?

EDIT:

Going further, may I be sure that back on client after response `Reciever`s will be invoked in exactly the same order in which their corresponding methods were accumulated?

Finally, is there a way to add some action that will be invoked at the end of response handling, after all `Receiver`s' actions?

I thought something like this may work:

```
requestContext.fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void response) {
        //Things to do after all receivers
    });
```

And it really seems to work as I expected but because all that Javadoc is telling me about `RequestContext.fire(Receiver)` method is:

> For receiving errors or validation failures only.

I'm not 100% sure whether my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, order of method invocations is preserved, both on the server-side and then back on the client side when calling `Reciever`s.

The queue is a simple `ArrayList` in which invocation objects are appended. On the server-side, they're processed in the order they're received.

The *`Request-Context`-level* `Receiver` is always called after the ones for invocations. Its `onSuccess` is always called, whatever the result of the invocations (even if they all fail), to signal that the batch of invocations was processed successfully. Its `onFailure` is only called in case of a *general failure*, i.e. a network error, or an error when (de)serializing requests/responses on the server-side.
See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/AbstractRequestContext.java?r=10835#345

Comment: Thanks once again, Thomas. I think it should be clearly indicated somewhere in docs. Invocation order does matter sometimes like in my case.

Comment: Isn't that already conveyed by the notion of _queue_? queue == FIFO, implying retained ordering.

Comment: If a word "queue" pop ups somewhere in the docs then allright. I must have overlooked it.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to include new part of my question (under "EDIT"), Thomas? I would be very grateful.